# Wordpress author change for all posts

Tags: wordpress

I'v got a page on Wordpress with 14000 posts in it. I'm looking for the way to change author for that posts programmatically.

Thanks for all answers.

Comment: If you have access to the SQL database, you could run a query on the posts you want to update to change the author

Comment: You could delete the author, and set it so the posts get the author you want automatically

Answer (score 0):

try to use this query in your sql database to change author of posts in bulk using author id, assigned in database table..

**`UPDATE wp_posts SET post_author=id_new_author WHERE post_author=id_old_author;`**